# Как выделить цветом значение строки/столбца/ячейки в Pandas Dataframe на Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colorama

Есть datafram на pandas. Нужно определенное значение строки/столбца/ячейки выделить цветом

Comment: Можно попробовать таблицу из Rich использовать (https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables.html), только таблицу pandas придется вручную конвертировать, и устанавливать для нужных ячеек нужный стиль

Comment: при добавление строки с переменной(table.add_row(vaqt, zayavkaMiq, balansi, maker, narx)) выходит ошибка: "table.add_row(vaqt, zayavkaMiq, balansi, maker, narx)
  File "/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rich/table.py", line 460, in add_row
    raise errors.NotRenderableError(
rich.errors.NotRenderableError: unable to render float; a string or other renderable object is required"

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать стилевую функцию, а затем применить ее к датафрейму, вот пример кода:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9]
})   

def highlight_value(value, color='yellow'):
    if value == 2:
        return f'background-color: {color}'
    return 

styled_df = df.style.applymap(highlight_value)
styled_df
```

В данном случае ячейка, в которой значение равно 2 выделится желтым цветом.

Comment: Я новичок в программирование) Можете полностью написать рабочий код с вашим примером? Я не смог выделить цветом

Comment: нужно ли импортировать какую то библиотеку?

Comment: @asterio у меня все работает просто с пандас, но я использую онлайн jupiter notebook на сайте Kaggle, на счет того, будет ли это работать через обычную среду разработки-не знаю(
Из коммента ниже, я не уверен, что через консоль будут цвета работать вообще...(

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы работаете в Jupyter notebook и у вас версия pandas 1.3+,  вы можете использовать встроенный стиль [`highlight_between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Highlight-Between).

Т.к. вы хотите выделить *только одно значение,* используйте это значение в обоих ключевых параметрах `left=` и `right=`, например так:

```
df.style.highlight_between(left=8, right=8)
```

*Результат:*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вам не нравится желтый цвет, вы можете попробовать другой:

```
df.style.highlight_between(left=8, right=8, color="springgreen")
```

*Результат:*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Примечание:*

- [Все возможные параметры](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.highlight_between.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.highlight_between),
- [все возможные имена цветов](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#named-colors).

Comment: Я использую через консоль(терминал)

Comment: Тогда лучше позабудьте на выделение чего-то цветом. :-(